# Defining function such that $f(x)=f(g(x))$ for a certain g

Tags: calculus, continuity

I am trying to find a function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^N$ continuous and another function $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ bijective and $\mathcal{C}^1$, such that

$f(x)=f(g(x)),\ \forall x\in[0,1]$

$g(0)=1$ and $g(1)=0$

Restrictions: $f$ cannot be constant and $g$ cannot be the map $x\mapsto 1-x$.

I've started defining $g(x)=1-x^2$, but how can I describe an explicit form of $f$ now? Only thing I can say about $f$ is that it must verify $f(0)=f(1)$.

Any hint?

Comment: My intuition says that unless $(g \circ g \circ \cdots \circ g)(x) = x$ for some order of composition, it will often turn out that constant $f$ are the only continuous solutions.

Comment: No, @mcd chose a function where $(g \circ g)(x) = x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose $g$ as a 'general' function you will have problems, because you then need $f(x)=f(g(x))=f(g(g(x)))= f(g(g(g(x)))) ...$ which is hard to guarantee. Therefore I would start with a function which has period 2, so $g(g(x))=x$, and monotonically decreasing on the interval $[0, 1]$, with $g(0)=1$, $g(1)=0$. For instance, $g(x)=\dfrac{a(x-1)}{(x-a)}$, for any $a$. Then you can define $f$ however you like for $x$ in $[0,k]$, where $k$ is the fixed point of the iteration (that is, the solution of $x=\dfrac{a(x-1)}{(x-a)}$, and then, for $x$ in $(k,1]$ define it by $f(x)=f(g(x))$. Now the condition is satisfied by definition for all $x$ in $(k,1]$ and, if $x$ is in  $[0,k]$, $g(x)$ is in $(k,1]$, so $f(g(x))=f(g(g(x)))=f(x)$ by the periodicity. I suggest choosing $a=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$; then the fixed point is $k=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Alternatively, if you want rational values, $a=\frac{25}{16}$ with $k=\frac{5}{8}$.